# Ошибка при выполнении click()

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Я пишу команду "найти элемент по xpath":

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tbl']/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/span[3]/i")
```

Тест проходит нормально, но когда я добавляю на этот элемент `click()`:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tbl']/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/span[3]/i").click()
```

Тест рушится, пишет ошибку:

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
> Message: Element is not clickable at point (1251.9833984375, 12.25). 
> Other element would receive the click: <ul class="nav top-links navbar-right"></ul>
> ```

Comment: Прежде чем кликать на элементе проверьте виден ли он, и не перекрывает ли его другой элемент страницы, в некоторых случаях надо прокрутить скролл чтобы он стал виден.

Comment: Спасибо решил проблему!

Comment: У элемента есть свойство типа `visible` но имейте ввиду, что оно далеко не всегда означает, что на элементе можно кликнуть если оно установлено в истину.

Answer (score 1):

Для питона вам надо самому написать функции проверки, вот как это в VB.NET я делаю.
Я при работе с элементами пользуюсь подобными функциями.

```
    Function checkVisibleWaitByElement(ByRef element As IWebElement, ByVal selector As String) As Boolean

        Try
            Dim elI As IWebElement = element.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector))

            If elI.Displayed = False Then
                Throw New ElementNotVisibleException
            End If

            Return True

        Catch ex As ElementNotVisibleException
            Return False
        Catch ex As NoSuchElementException
            Return False
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

Вызывать надо в цикле, с задержкой, для ожидания появления элемента например.

```
    Sub waitVisibleByElement(ByRef element As IWebElement, ByVal selector As String)

        While (Not Me.checkVisibleWaitByElement(element, selector))
            Thread.Sleep(200)
        End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: Я попробовал скролл вроде помогло: browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")